# Maven Eclipse Debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, debugging

I created simple *hello world* program with Maven and Eclipse. I can Run and Debug as Java application. I was able to create configuration under Create,Manage,Run > Java Application  as Helloworld. Within this configuration I could assign Project and class.

I have existing Maven project in Eclipse. This is significantly different. It does not appear with Package Explorer as a Maven or Java project, as it does not show any packages /src/main/java but as file folders (no icons for Maven or Java next to file folders).

When I click and attempt to configure this under Create,Manage,Run > Java Application, I am not able to browse to project or classes.

How would one go about Debugging this Maven project in Eclipse?

Project does have Create,Manage,Run > Maven Build configured. Compiles into Jar fine and pulls in necessary libraries with dependent pom XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess Eclipse does not know, that your Maven project is a Maven project.
You can change this as follows:
Right click with mouse on your project => "Configure" => "Convert to Maven Project"

This should trigger automatically a build and then you should see the Java and Maven icons.